# Jade-Lang + Laravel + select option

Tags: laravel, pug

I have my jade file and I have a select input setup with the following(using Laravel as well):

```
option(value="1", selected!='{!! $client->single_check == 1 ? "true" : "false" !!}') Yes
option(value="0", selected!='{!! $client->single_check == 0 ? "true" : "false" !!}') No
```

I am fairly new to Jade so I am trying to figure out how to use this correctly. Obviously selected="true" doesn't work it has to be selected=true, or even a way just to make it say "selected" or it just doesn't show selected at all. Does anyone know the correct way I should be doing this? If I take away the "!=" and just make it "=" it wont work. If I take away the quote marks it wont work either. I have a feeling this is something simple like I'm just not finding it in the documents.

This morning I tried creating a mixin as well and using it inside the option tag but it didnt work either.

```
 option(value="1", +lv('{{ $client->single_check == 1 ? "selected" : "" }}')) Yes
 option(value="0", +lv('{{ $client->single_check == 0 ? "selected" : "" }}')) No
```

Mixin:

```
mixin lv(content)
  !{content}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a better way to do this let me know and I will mark yours as the answer! For now I just created a whole new option mixin:

```
+lopt('1', '{{ $client->single_check == 1 ? "selected" : ""}}', 'Yes')  
+lopt('0', '{{ $client->single_check == 0 ? "selected" : ""}}', 'No')
```

Mixin:

```
mixin lopt(val, sel, text)
   | <option value="!{val}" !{sel}>!{text}</option>
```